# Dynamic sorting with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a situation where I have a large partition/row with many cells/values. I need to query this row for all the cells sorted by a value (one of the keys). This sort value is dynamic, and changes of often. You can't update any of the primary keys of cassandra because it changes how the data is stored. So, how do I do this? Does cassandra not support normalized queries that the sort can change at any given moment?

Comment: could you provide an example? I'm not sure I understand what you try to do

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not support normalized queries where the sort can change at any given moment. You can do sort on the client or using additional tools like Spark.